# Create a POJO for a nested JSON for Retrofit

Tags: java, json, gson, retrofit, pojo

I am trying to create a POJO for the following JSON.

```
{
  "key1":"value1",
  "key2":"value2",
  "hashmap":
  {
     "1":"val"
     "2":"val"
     ...
     "n":"val"
  }
}
```

Now the POJO I tried was

```
public class MyPOJO{
  @SerializedName{"key1"}
  @Expose
  private String key1;

  @SerializedName{"key2"}
  @Expose
  private String key2;

  @SerializedName{"hashmap"}
  @Expose
  private HashMap<String,String> hMap;

}
```

The problem is that the hashmap is not getting serialized. It is just ignored when the class gets serialized.

This is how I use the class in Retrofit.

```
@POST("/endpoint/")
void foo(@Body MyPojo, Callback<Response> callback);
```

One suggestion I came across is to use an inner class instead of the Hashmap. But my keys are dynamic, I cannot define variables for each key. I need to get the Hashmap serialized.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/   use this website to generate pojo from json

Comment: Won't work, my hashmap keys are dynamic. Not fixed. FYI, I use jsonschema2pojo to create my POJOs otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should have a look at retrofit converters and use a converter which supports maps.

Or use a custom converter.